# What goes through my .NET core middleware pipeline

Tags: .net, http, asp.net-core

So I have a middleware implemented that blocks requests based on Basic Auth in the header at the moment. And I'm then using Selenium to open a browser window with the application. Here I thought I would need to implement some simple cookie handling to be able to click around on the website through some links. So far though it's working without any cookies. It feels like some very basic network traffic rules going on here that it keeps sending the same headers. But I can't help but wonder when this will come back to haunt me, will it keep working as long as I stay on  the same domain, or will it break during some scenarios?

Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseAuthentication();
        //app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMiddleware>();

        app.UseBrowserLink();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

And the middleware:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ILogger<SimpleAuthMiddleware> logger)
    {
        bool auth = false;
        string username;
        try
        {
            var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
            logger.LogInformation("AuthHeader: " + authHeader);
            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
            username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];
            logger.LogInformation("Found username & password: " + username + ":" + password);
            if (username == "testname" && password == "testpass")
            {
                auth = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        if (auth)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Auth Passed");
            await _next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Auth Failed");
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your `Configure` method.

Comment: @Dai Edited to add configure method and middleware code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this won't come back to haunt you, cause according to your code, I saw you have disable both `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`, and use your custom authentication (which is not actually Authentication cause it not set `User` info that represent and stick with the HttpRequest, it just allow the request to pass through) middleware. Which, again, not validate the user by cookie, but on the header.

So... even if the cookie is there, that won't matter anyway, cause you're not using it since the first place.

Comment: Ye, I tried using more proper, but getting it to work with selenium was such a pain, and it's not really needed for this one. But it will keep sending the initial header with the Auth field until we close the website then?

Comment: As long as your request doesn't have to go through the c# things, you're safe just sending Auth header for initial request only. But If your use case got to take some action with the c#, you got to attach the header back again. That's all up to your use case my friend.

Comment: That's the thing though, those prints in my middleware goes off with the same values when I navigate within my application by links, so I guess it's resending the same header. And I'm wondering if it's safe to assume it will keep doing that until I leave the domain completely, or send an entirely new request, say for posting data or requesting a file.

Comment: Default asp net core doesn't come with header propagating, so this must be a http forward request, which will keep your origin request information. As long as you doesn't touch the `HttpClient` in asp net core, you are basically safe.